# TIFFPackBitsCompressor - NPE?

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, jai

I'm using com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFPackBitsCompressor to try and encode an array of tiff bytes I have using PackBits. I'm unfamiliar with this class and haven't been finding many examples on how to use it. But, when following the javadoc, I've been getting an NPE every time I try to encode my data. So far as I can see, none of my values are null. I've tried these tests with multiple values at this point, but below is my most recent iteration:

```
                TIFFPackBitsCompressor pack = new TIFFPackBitsCompressor();
                //bImageFromConvert is a 16-bit BufferedImage with all desired data.
                short[] bufferHolder = ((DataBufferUShort) bImageFromConvert.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
                //Since bImageFromConvert is 16-bits, the short array isn't the right length. 
                //The below conversion handles tihs issue
                byte[] byteBuffer = convertShortToByte(bufferHolder);
                //I'm not entirely sure what this int[] in the parameters should be. 
                //For now, it is a test int[] array containing all 1s
                int[] testint = new int[byteBuffer.length];
                Arrays.fill(testint, 1);
                //0 offset. dimWidth = 1760, dimHeight = 2140. Not sure what that last param is supposed to be in layman's terms.
                //npe thrown at this line.
                int testOut = pack.encode(byteBuffer, 0, dimWidth, dimHeight, testint, 1);
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what's happening? Also, if available, does anyone know a better way to encode my TIFF files using PackBits in a java program?

Let me know if there's anything to make my question clearer.

Thank you!

Comment: Where's the stack trace? Anyway, I don't think you are supposed to use the compressor yourself, instead it's used by the JAI ImageIO TIFF plugin (the `TIFFImageWriter`) when you specify "PackBits" as compression type in the `ImageWriteParam`. You may also pass a compressor instance in the param, if you cast it to `TIFFImageWriteParam` first, but this is more useful for custom compressions not known by the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you are not supposed to use the `TIFFPackBitsCompressor` directly, instead it's used internally by the JAI ImageIO TIFF plugin (the `TIFFImageWriter`) when you specify "PackBits" as compression type in the `ImageWriteParam`. You may also pass a compressor instance in the param, if you cast it to `TIFFImageWriteParam` first, but this is more useful for custom compressions not known by the plugin.

Also note that the compressor will only write PackBits compressed pixel data, it will *not* create a full TIFF file.

The normal way of writing a PackBits compressed TIFF file is:

```
BufferedImage image = ...; // Your input image

ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next(); // Assuming a TIFF plugin is installed

try (ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(...)) { // Your output file or stream
    writer.setOutput(out);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionType("PackBits");

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
}

writer.dispose();
```

The above code should work fine using both JAI ImageIO and the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO TIFF plugins.

---

PS: [PackBits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits) is a very simple compression algorithm based on [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) of *byte* data. As 16 bit data may vary wildly between the high and low byte of a single sample, PackBits is generally not a good choice for compression of such data.

As stated in my comments, using completely random values I got the following results:

```
Compression      | File size
-----------------|-----------------
None             |  7 533 680 bytes
PackBits         |  7 593 551 bytes
LZW w/predictor  | 10 318 091 bytes
ZLib w/predictor | 10 318 444 bytes
```

This is not very surprising, as completely random data isn't generally compressible (without data loss). For a linear gradient, which may be more similar to "photographic" image data I got completely different results:

```
Compression      | File size
-----------------|-----------------
None             |  7 533 680 bytes
PackBits         |  7 588 779 bytes
LZW w/predictor  |    200 716 bytes
ZLib w/predictor |    144 136 bytes
```

As you see, here the LZW and Deflate/Zlib algorithms (with predictor step) performs MUCH better. For "real" data, there's likely more noise, so your results is likely somewhere in between these extremes.

Comment: While a file is writing and is in the tiff format, it is roughly twice the size of the original file. If it helps, the short[] holds wrapped bytes for a 16 bit image. The image is 1760x2140 pixels, and the original image size is 7,532,800 bytes (no metadata, just pixel bytes). The file resulting from this code 15,119,390 bytes (including tiff metadata).

Comment: @Sarah You have just discovered that PackBits is a very inefficient compression algorithm for your data (it is inefficient for 16 bit data in general). Using the code above, I compressed a black image (still 1760x2140 16 bits/pixel) to 120 Kbytes. Filling the image with random noise, the file size became 7,5 Mbytes. Using LZW or ZLib with predictor gave sizes roughly 10 Mbytes, but it may still yield better results for you, as your data isn't random.